# sending broadcast message from the client side in socket.io

Tags: javascript, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

In the socket.io client socket section of the doc http://socket.io/docs/client-api/#io#socket refers to Socket docs, which implies both server Socket object and client Socket object are the same.

Also the docs http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#default-room here has the following code which has a broadcast object attached to socket object. ie. socket.broadcast.

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('say to someone', function(id, msg){
    socket.broadcast.to(id).emit('my message', msg);
  });
});
```

However the **socket.broadcast** property is not accessible on the client side. It throws Type Error. **Does this mean that broadcasting can not be done from client side**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, broadcasting cannot be done from the client side. This is because they may both be sockets but they are not considered the same. Check out these two:

[Socket.io-client](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io-client/blob/master/lib/socket.js)
and [Socket.io](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/blob/master/lib/socket.js)